# FullCalendar using private google calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

We're using fullcalendar on our website and it works very well, the problem we have is that fullcalendar gets info from a public google calendar. Our calendar needs to be private. Also, the authentication needs to be automatic (no need to have a button to authorize from google). How do I go about this? I've seen some similar threads here but nothing seems to have the answer that we need.

Comment: To fulfil both of those criteria (private calendar and no login screen) you need to fetch the data on the server-side via the Google Calendar API and a Service account. Use your server-side code to fetch the events from Google and then convert the data into fullCalendar's JSON format to show in fullCalendar.

Comment: Hi ADyson, Sounds interesting. I can't seem to find info on how to do this on google's docs. Can I do this via JS + PHP?

Comment: I'm struggling to see how you can't find anything. https://developers.google.com/calendar/ has guides, API references and samples including PHP.